# The back button does not work in the responsive menu

Tags: javascript, css, responsive

What I want to do is to return to the previous menu when the return button is clicked, can you help? I'm leaving a link on how to write the code here

```
const submenutitle = document.querySelector('.submenutitle');
```

https://codepen.io/tolgagnydnn/pen/abWmMpp

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post code here, especially if you can post a reproducible example

Comment: @Kinglish he posted code in the link

Comment: But its hard to understand what you did there. can you explain what you did?

Comment: I actually made a responsive menu there. I couldn't make my back button, that's all @Kinglish

Comment: which one is the return button? I can't read the language

Comment: I made the code readable. Return button belonging to submenutitle class @Kinglish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was you had two listeners and the second (the back button) was being overwritten by the first (because the back button is part of the group of listeners from the first set). Essentially, the back button had 2 event listeners on it. I consolidated them. I had to change some of the code, so that it would find the right element to add/remove classes from:

```
for (const mobilemainmenuitem of mobilemainmenuitems) {
  mobilemainmenuitem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const submenu = e.target;
    if (submenu.classList.contains("btn"))
      submenu
        .closest(".mobilesubmenu")
        .classList.remove("showleft", "showvisibility");
    else
      submenu
        .closest("li")
        .querySelector(".mobilesubmenu")
        .classList.add("showleft", "showvisibility");
  });
}
```

https://codepen.io/kinglish/pen/OJmRevq?editors=1111